# Does NLog support sending an snmp trap as a target?

Tags: c#, snmp, nlog

Does NLog support sending an snmp trap as a target? If not, does anyone have any suggestions? Can I write a custom target to send a snmp trap?

Answer (score 2):

There is no SNMP-Target for NLog. See the [list of available Targets](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Targets).

However, it is really simple to develop a custom Target. See [how to write a Target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target).

Comment: Thanks for the like on writing a target. Does anyone have a .net example on how to send a snmp trap?

Comment: @DougHawes - Sending SNMP traps with C#: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/b36f23ac-6a3b-4b44-9b04-37b72b751200

Comment: @DougHawes, there are several SNMP libraries available for you explore how to send TRAP in C#.NET, http://www.lextm.com/2007/12/product-review-snmp-libraries-for-net.html